# Fountain grass blade interact with ground

Tags: geometry-nodes, geometry

I'm trying to create a procedural tall grass with blades that, when they reach the ground, they lie flat or bounce off it naturally as in real life.  Here's what I have so far. I'm looking for a way to make the transition to the ground more curved and gradual. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
[image: long blade of grass]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be a solution:

[image: Rendered result]

[image: Mix Waveforms]

Here I first create two different waveforms, which I mix based on the curve factor.

I then mix the resulting curve a second time with the positions of the original curve.

However, here I also apply the `Map Range` node so that I get a smoother transition between the mixed waveforms and the original curve. This node also controls the transition between the two curves.

[image: Node Tree]

[image]

---

**Update: Method 2**

Here is a second variant:

[image]

This uses only one waveform, but notes whether the position is below zero.

[image]

*(I'll explain this in more detail in due time).*

[image]

Comment: This is very helpful.  I have struggled for hours however to try and find a method to implement this on multiple realized curve instances, only some of which reach below 0 (ground) level as a fountain grass would do. I'm applying blade curl after curve lines are instanced with vector rotate/set position based on offset from center point.  Only the outer blades will reach the ground.  I'm wondering now if a geometry proximity node and a plane might be a better approach?  Something to try.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why your idea of a grass resembles a path of a bouncing ball:

[Youtube: Modeling a Bounce by The Art of Code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IKVM4DAQ840)

But you can reproduce the formula from the video in nodes:

[image]

And now you can use it in your setup and further process it - in my case I was just lazy so I played with a color ramp to get something at least moderately looking like a grass (I still don't get it why the grass is supposed to bounce rather than lay flat):

[image]

[image]